# Como verificar un array como true sin depender de un indice específico?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
var level90 = [
    g.indexOf('90') != -1, // level 90 = level90[0]
    g.indexOf('91') != -1,
    g.indexOf('92') != -1,
    g.indexOf('93') != -1,
    g.indexOf('94') != -1,
    g.indexOf('95') != -1,
    g.indexOf('96') != -1,
    g.indexOf('97') != -1,
    g.indexOf('98') != -1,
    g.indexOf('99') != -1,
    g.indexOf('100') != -1,
    g.indexOf('101') != -1,
 ];
```

Y tengo la siguiente variable `String`

```
var g = "Hola tengo 101 años";
```

Y quiero hacer un `if` que me retorne true si tiene el número `101` en la variable, fácilmente podría hacer:

```
if (level90[11]) {
 // Operación
}
```

Pero tengo la duda de que como se puede verificar sin especificar el indice del `array`, creo que con un `for` funcionaria, pero no se me ocurre como .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede verificar si retorna `True` cada elemento iterado con un `for` simple o un por el método [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) para luego obtener el `index` dentro del `for` accediendo a la variable `i` y en el  [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach)  a `index`.

En su ejemplo la variable contiene `101` , iniciará a ejecutar desde la posición `0` del `array`

> 1 Iteración -> `g.indexOf('90')!=-1` // `false`
>     2 Iteración -> `g.indexOf('91')!=-1` // `false`
>     3 Iteración -> `g.indexOf('92')!=-1` //  `false`
>       ....
>     12 Iteración -> `g.indexOf('101')!=-1` // `true`

```js
var g = "Hola tengo 101 años";
var array =[  
    g.indexOf('90') != -1, 
    g.indexOf('91') != -1,
    g.indexOf('92') != -1,
    g.indexOf('93') != -1,
    g.indexOf('94') != -1,
    g.indexOf('95') != -1,
    g.indexOf('96') != -1,
    g.indexOf('97') != -1,
    g.indexOf('98') != -1,
    g.indexOf('99') != -1,
    g.indexOf('100') != -1,
    g.indexOf('101') != -1
];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 if(array[i]){ /* Verificará si g.indexOff retorna true para c/item del array */
   console.log(i);
   /* Operaciones*/
  }
}

array.forEach(function(item,index){
  /* if(item) es Equivalente a item==true*/
  if(item) { /* Verificará si g.indexOff retorna true para cada item del array */
console.log(index);
  }
});
```

Comment: Perfecta, me podriás explicar algo? , donde el primer if retorna true? y segundo he estado aprendiendo y el forEach no lo entendí mucho de donde sacan item e index? podrías explicarme eso o pasarme documentación que explique eso ? gracias.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian añadí los enlaces de la documentación oficial de `forEach`

Comment: Muchas gracias ,no me di cuenta de lo emocionado hehe

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i in level90) {
  if(level90[i] == 101) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

De esa forma puedes verificar si se encuentra el valor 101 dentro de tu array.

puedes crear un metodo que te retorne true o false dependiendo de la condicion

```
var tieneElemento = function(array,elemento) {

  for(var i in array) {
      if(array[i] == elemento) {
        return true;
      }
  }

  return false;
}

//lo ejecutas de esta manera
if(tieneElemento(level90,101)){
  console.log("se encuentra el elemento dentro del array")
}
```

Comment: Okey, pero ese en ese if , su operación en sí es retornar true , pero yo quiero hacer muchas otras acciones , que hago? , valla que se nota que estoy aprendiendo..

Answer (score -1):

¿Qué clase de problema estás resolviendo ?, puede ser que no estés usando la variable correcta. Otra cosa `for (var i in objeto) ...` se utiliza para iterar sobre un objeto y no un array (puedes leer más al respecto en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in)).

Comment: Lo que necesitaba es que verificara sin importar el indice

Comment: @emartini javascript es un lenguaje basado en objetos, el array de javascript se interpreta como un objeto.

Comment: No @IvanKoop, no debes usar `for...in` en Array en JS, en la documentación de MDN indica en detalle por qué: "La sentencia for..in itera  sobre todas las propiedades de un objeto, en un **orden arbitriario**. Para cada una de las propiedades, se ejecuta la sentencia especificada..."


`Note: for...in should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index order is important.`